# (SQL) User tables are separated into two sections

Tags: oracle-11g, sqlplus

[image: Tables grouped into two sections]

Using SQL Plus, I create 13 tables via an .sql file, each containing primary and foreign keys. When I execute "select table_name from user_tables;" they are displayed in this partitioned fashion. The number of tables in each partition varies each time the tables are dropped then recreated. Each table is unique/there are no repeating tables.

I am having difficulties interfacing with the DB via php/OCI (I can access the column headings, but no records are found) and was wondering if this could be the reason. This is after multiple INSERTs, and SQL PLUS queries confirm the existence of records.

Overall, what does this grouping mean, is it problematic and how can I resolve the tables into one grouping?

Comment: Perhaps this is some paging setting of the interface you use for connecting to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just the paging in SQL*Plus. By default the paging value is 14, that includes a blank line at the start of each page, the line with column headers, the line with heading separators (hyphens) and the rest (11 rows) is for user data.

If you increase the pagesize, the result of your query will fit in to 1 page:

```
set pagesize 20
```

It has nothing to do with php/OCI.

[SET PAGES[IZE] {14 | n}](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG095)